# How to refresh application deployed in Linux machine

Tags: linux, ssh, putty, application

I have deployed `angular` application in Sandbox Linux machine. When replacing data in `assets` folder those changes are not reflecting in website. Though I am using `sudo service restart httpd` command.

I am using `Putty` command prompt and connecting to server via ssh

How can I reflect the changes or recompile code/application using commands?

Answer (score 1):

Try restarting with `ng serve --live-reload` or with `sudo`